# Error: There is a column named in table "*SELECT*", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query

Tags: postgresql, insert

Assume we have a simple table,

```
CREATE TABLE foo ( a int PRIMARY KEY, b int );
```

I'm wanting to write a complex query inside and refer to that query

```
INSERT INTO foo
  SELECT 5 AS z
ON CONFLICT (a)
DO UPDATE SET b = z;
```

However when I execute that I'm getting an error like this,

```
ERROR:  column "z" does not exist
LINE 4:     DO UPDATE SET b = z;
                              ^
```

> HINT:  There is a column named "z" in table "*SELECT*", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query.

Is there a way to make a structure like this work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PostgreSQL doesn't see the column by the alias you've given it. That's not how it's parsed. It sees the `z` by the name you've tried to insert it as `a` on a psuedo-table `EXCLUDED`. You want to do this instead,

```
INSERT INTO foo
  SELECT 5 AS z
ON CONFLICT (a)
DO UPDATE SET b = EXCLUDED.a;
```

For more information [see the docs on `INSERT`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html),

> The `SET` and `WHERE` clauses in `ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE` have access to the existing row using the table's name (or an alias), and to rows proposed for insertion using the special excluded table.